# Realizar búsqueda en DataGridView con datos precargados c#

Tags: c#, stored-procedure, dataset

tengo una duda que quisiera que me ayuden para resolver, tengo un formulario el cual me carga datos desde un `Dataset` que a su vez proviene de un procedimiento almacenado, la pregunta es podría buscar en el `Datagridview` una vez cargado el resultado desde el sp ?.

```
 public void Busqueda_Sec_UD(TextBox txtBusq,DataGridView dataGridDesc)
    {
        String campo = txtBusq.Text;
        try
        {
            String connstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Trabajo"].ToString();
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstring))
            {
                conn.Open();
                string sql = String.Format("SELECT DS.Des_CodEmpleado as COD,DS.Des_CodSec AS CODSEC, S.SECCION as CONSEC,Des_Concepto AS CONCEPTO,DS.Des_Descuento AS DESCUENTO," +
                "DS.Des_Fecha AS FECHA FROM HIS_MOV_DESCUENTO DS INNER JOIN TBL_SECCION S ON DS.Des_CodSec = S.ID_CODIGO where DS.Des_CodSec like '{0}%' order by DS.Des_Fecha DESC", campo);
                Console.WriteLine(sql);
                if (conn != null)
                {
                    dataGridDesc.Enabled = true;
                    SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter1 = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
                    SqlCommandBuilder comm = new SqlCommandBuilder(sqlDataAdapter1);
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    sqlDataAdapter1.Fill(ds, "Hora");
                    try
                    {
                        dataGridDesc.DataSource = ds.Tables["Hora"];
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("ERROR: " + ex.Message, "ERROR!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ERROR: " + ex.Message, "ERROR!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Este es el código que uso en el cual yo le envió la sentencia para que proceda a buscar, pero existe la posibilidad que coger los datos del `Dataset` que cargo con el sp para realizar la búsqueda y no tener que enviar nuevamente la sentencia sql y basarme la búsqueda desde los nombre de cada columna del sp?.

De antemano agradezco su ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Después de googlear un poco así quedaría en donde con el nombre de la columna del `DatagridView` se procede a buscar lo solicitado.

```
 public void Busqueda_Sec_UD(TextBox txtBusq,DataGridView dataGridDesc)
    {
        String campo = txtBusq.Text;
        try
        {
            String connstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Trabajo"].ToString();
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstring))
            {
                BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
                bs.DataSource = dataGridDesc.DataSource;
                bs.Filter = "CONSEC like '%" + campo + "%'";
                dataGridDesc.DataSource = bs;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ERROR: " + ex.Message, "ERROR!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Mi solución seria la siguiente hacerla por medio de JS, creo que puede ser un poco mas dinámico

```
function Search_Gridview(strKey, gvTV) {
            var strData = strKey.value.toLowerCase().split(" ");
            var tblData = $find('<%= rgvAsignacion.ClientID %>');
            var toto = tblData.get_masterTableView();
            var rowData;
            for (var i = 0; i < toto.get_dataItems().length; i++) {
                rowData = toto._dataItems[i]._element.innerText;
                var styleDisplay = 'none';
                for (var j = 0; j < strData.length; j++) {
                    if (rowData.toLowerCase().indexOf(strData[j]) >= 0)
                        styleDisplay = '';
                    else {
                        styleDisplay = 'none';
                        break;
                    }
                }
                toto._dataItems[i]._element.style.display = styleDisplay;
            }
        }
```

y para usarlo en el texbox o input

```
onkeyup="Search_Gridview(this, 'rgvAsignacion')"
```

espero te sirva!

Answer (score 0):

considero que la manera apropiada sería omitiendo esa declaración de la conexión, yo lo haría de la siguiente manera, reutilizando tu código:

Este método obtiene los datos de la bd y los vincula a un bindinsource para poder filtrar, y a su vez mostrarlo en el grid

```
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
    public void CargarDatos()
    {//Cargar datos vinculandolo a un bindinsource y mostrarlo en el grid
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Trabajo"].ConnectionString))
            {
                string sql = String.Format("SELECT DS.Des_CodEmpleado as COD,DS.Des_CodSec AS CODSEC, S.SECCION as CONSEC,Des_Concepto AS CONCEPTO,DS.Des_Descuento AS DESCUENTO," +
                "DS.Des_Fecha AS FECHA FROM HIS_MOV_DESCUENTO DS INNER JOIN TBL_SECCION S ON DS.Des_CodSec = S.ID_CODIGO  order by DS.Des_Fecha DESC");
                //where DS.Des_CodSec like '{0}%'

                if (conn != null)
                {
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter1 = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
                    sqlDataAdapter1.Fill(dt);
                    try
                    {
                        bs.DataSource = dt;
                        dataGridDesc.DataSource = bs;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("ERROR: " + ex.Message, "ERROR!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ERROR: " + ex.Message, "ERROR!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Esta función realmente es la que se encarga del filtro, ya que el bindinsource tiene la propiedad Filter con la que se realiza valga la redundancia el filtro.

```
void FiltrarDatos()
    {//Filtrar y mostrar en grid
        try
        {
            if (bs.DataSource != null)
            {
                bs.Filter = $"Des_CodSec like '%{txt1.Text}%'";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Filtrando...", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }
    }
```

De esta forma se usa el filtro en el evento TextChanged del textbox

```
private void Txt1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FiltrarDatos();
    }
```

Espero te sea de ayuda.